# Overcome repetition in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Suppose my `graphql` API allows me to manage `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC`.

Those models have very simple `typeDefs`:

```
type ModelA {
  id: ID!
  tags: [SomeComplexTagType!]
}

type ModelB {
  id: ID!
  tags: [SomeComplexTagType!]
}

type ModelC {
  id: ID!
  tags: [SomeComplexTagType!]
}
```

In order for users of the API to add tags to `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC` the following mutations are provided:

```
type Mutation {
  addTagToModelA(id: ID!, tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
  addTagToModelB(id: ID!, tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
  addTagToModelC(id: ID!, tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
}
```

What is the graphql recommended way to get rid of the repetive nature in this API design?

As far as I understand mutations are always top level elements of the Mutation type in graphql. That means, my resolver function for `addTagToModelX` will never be passed an instance of `ModelX` as its parent, i.e. something like this will never work:

```
type Mutation {
  ModelA(id: ID!) {
    addTagToX(tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
  }
  ModelB(id: ID!) {
    addTagToX(tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
  }
  ModelC(id: ID!) {
    addTagToX(tag: SomeComplexTagType!): Boolean
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good solution while digging into the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#addassigneestoassignable).

Summary:

1. They use [global node ids](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-global-node-ids) which allow them to conclude the object type from the ID, because the ID is base64 encoded and contains that information.
2. For my scenario this would mean:
   2.1) Make `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC` implement `Taggable`
   2.2) Introduce mutation `addTagToTaggable` accepting an `ID` from `Taggable`
   2.3) In the resolver extract the object type from `ID`, query object from database, add Tag etc.
   2.4) Profit

Comment: Has your thinking evolved on this by any chance? The GitHub approach seems slightly convoluted - which doesn't reflect well on GraphQL. Could you post example code for your solution, please? Cheers.